# How can I delete my Ask Different account?

Tags: support, faq

If I decide I don't want to have an account, can I delete it?

Comment: I ask this hypothetically since we've had a few requests of this lately as moderators and wanted there to be a place for people to find an answer to this question.

Comment: You scared me there for a second!

Comment: The general help section is also GOLD - really well done IMO. http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/

Answer (score 3):

Account deletion is initiated by you and completed by staff that reviews the deletion queue.

This help guide covers the mechanics:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion

You may not have to do anything if the system is going to delete your account if it detects it as abandoned. Flag one of your posts for moderator assistance if you just need to remove some personal information or remove your name from one post.

The content you contributed is licensed to the community, so your content will remain after you delete your account, just not with your name associated to the content.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/licensing

[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/)

Lastly, double check which account you are deleting if you happen to have more than one Stack Exchange account.